# treeview, addobject, del object

Tags: delphi, treeview

Вопрос по деревьям и нодам.

Пробую изучать TreeView. Также, считаю - что будет неплохим пособием новичку при изучении, т.к. инфо довольно скудная.

Вот сейчас есть такой код (это максимум моих знаний о компоненте (сам исходник, тоже могу скинуть куда надо, чтобы не руками набирать. среда D10, starter)):

что читалось и откуда был составлен пример ниже

> {начало}
>
> http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=23601
>
> http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-firemonkey/thread1111428.html
>
> http://itearn.ru/goto/349
>
> http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=192541
>
> **плюс:** гдето описание самого TV, где помню сказано что-то типа "вы можете добавлять итемы, а также объекты к нему, однако, после уничтожения
>   итемов - *сами объекты не уничтожаются*"
>
> {конец}

Картинка.

[image: http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1704/de/12b0c557e580.png]

Код.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tv1: TTreeView;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    Button4: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button5: TButton;
    Button6: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tv1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

Type
  TMyNode=record
          nom:integer;
          comm:string[100];
  end;

 TMyNode2 = class
  public
    nom: Integer;
    comm: String;
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyNode:TMyNode;
  MyNode2:TMyNode2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); // add node
var x: TTreeNode;
begin
x:=tv1.Items.Add(tv1.Selected,edit1.Text+' '+inttostr(round(random(100))));
x.ImageIndex:=1;x.SelectedIndex:=x.ImageIndex;x.StateIndex:=x.ImageIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject); // add child node
var x: TTreeNode;
begin
x:=tv1.Items.AddChild(tv1.Selected,'Child '+edit1.Text+' '+inttostr(round(random(100))));
x.ImageIndex:=2;x.SelectedIndex:=x.ImageIndex;x.StateIndex:=x.ImageIndex;
tv1.Selected.Expand(true);x.Selected:=true;x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); // del node (if not 1st)
var x,y: TTreeNode;
begin
y:=tv1.Items[0];x:=tv1.Selected;
if x<>y then x.Delete else showmessage('Do not del 1st node!');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); // add node (v.2 as object)
var x: TTreeNode;
begin
{ **** // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
MyNode.nom:=1;
MyNode.comm:='mytest comment';
}
MyNode2:=TMyNode2.Create;
MyNode2.nom:=round(random(1000));
MyNode2.comm:=inttostr(MyNode2.nom)+' comment '+inttostr(MyNode2.nom);
x:=tv1.Items.AddObject(tv1.Selected,edit1.Text+' '+inttostr(round(random(1000))),pointer(MyNode2{MyNode})); // **** // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
x.ImageIndex:=3;x.SelectedIndex:=x.ImageIndex;x.StateIndex:=x.ImageIndex;
tv1.Selected.Expand(true);x.Selected:=true;x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject); // add child node (v.2 as object)
var x: TTreeNode;
begin
MyNode2:=TMyNode2.Create;
MyNode2.nom:=round(random(1000));
MyNode2.comm:=inttostr(MyNode2.nom)+' child comment '+inttostr(MyNode2.nom);
x:=tv1.Items.AddChildObject(tv1.Selected,edit1.Text+' '+inttostr(round(random(1000))),pointer(MyNode2));
x.ImageIndex:=4;x.SelectedIndex:=x.ImageIndex;x.StateIndex:=x.ImageIndex;
tv1.Selected.Expand(true);x.Selected:=true;x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject); // del node (if not 1st) and "as" object
var x,y: TTreeNode;
begin
y:=tv1.Items[0];x:=tv1.Selected;
if x<>y then begin
//class(x.tMyNode2(node.Data)).Free; // **** // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
x.Delete;
end else showmessage('Do not del 1st node!');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); // on create - add data 2 1st node
var x: TTreeNode;
begin
MyNode2:=TMyNode2.Create;
MyNode2.nom:=100001;
MyNode2.comm:='1st node comment';
x:=tv1.Items[0];
x.Data:=pointer(MyNode2);
end;

procedure TForm1.tv1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode); // look node prop.
begin
if Node=nil then Caption:='Not select' else
if Node.Data=nil then Caption:=Format('Nom: %d, Im.Ind: %d',[Integer(Node.Index),Integer(Node.ImageIndex)])
else
Caption:=Format('Nom: %d, Im.Ind: %d, MyNode.Nom: %d, Comm: %s',[Integer(Node.Index),Integer(Node.ImageIndex),integer(TMyNode2(node.Data).nom), string(TMyNode2(node.Data).comm)]);
end;

end.
```

**В коде - 2 варианта добавления\удаления итемов, обычный и с объектами.**
С первым вариантом вопросов нет. А вот с удалением второго - да.

**Вопросы:**

1. В button3.click (помечены // **** // !!!!!!!!!!!!!) - почему нельзя вставить ссылку на запись, а только на класс? в описании говорится, что "вы можете использовать ссылки на любые объекты"
2. Больше всего беспокоит вопрос об удалении объектов - проц.
   Button6Click - там заремлено. где затык. Покажите, как правильно удалить ноду с объектом (или только объект)
   и правда ли, что если удалить итем из дерева - объект останется?
3. Правильно ли все? Все что знаю о TV тут. Может гдето что-то не верно?

***Отдельный бонус.***

4. Как правильно сохранить (и потом загрузить) все ноды из Tv1? Т.к. Tv1.savetofile('d:\1.txt') и обратная, загружают только дерево, без ссылок на дату и картинок. Если не сложно.

Спасибо.

Comment: вы как думаете сами эта куча неформатированного кода вообще читаема?

Comment: :( блин. я же все подписал, дал картинку: есть treeview; клавиши к нему (расписаны в коде как "//") и каждый клик подписан :( без проблем, сделаю как нужно - напишите как? или могу "усилить комментарии к строкам кода" - больше  их написать? и "читаема"??? - см. имя процедуры и после нее "//"  :( в Delphi у мну все красиво.. тут нет видимо. ранее писал - могу код скинуть в несколько мест - там если откр. будет у всех ОК.

Comment: вот http://rgho.st/6bGQbHFHn или http://my-files.ru/4jpwkk или http://www.fayloobmennik.net/6963950 или http://файлообменник.рф/d3n2xmew5oeu.html - это сам проект D10 Starter

Comment: вы вообще попробуйте [справку](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView) в оригинале почитать, вероятно много вопросов исчезнут. а то у вас ссылки то на форумы, то на VCL, то на FMX, то еще чего. RTFM, как говорится

Comment: согласен. но если справку в оригинале читать - этот форум зачем? :( ну ок, "вопрос - уменьшаю до отв. на п.2". там вот непонятно, никак не могу понять, как (и надо ли) удалить объект правильно. не сердитесь плз, вы мну ткните в нужное место, а далее, сам смогу. ну а если долго или никак - тоже скажите, попробую у буржуинов :(

Comment: у дерева есть событие удаления узла. в нем вы можете вызывать осовбодить связанный (`free()`)объект или запись (`dispose` и т.п. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В `Node.data` можно присвоить любой объект или указатель на запись.
   Удаление объекта или указателя зависит от способа создания. 
   То есть `Dispose(PMyRecord(Node.data));`
   или `TMyClass(Node.Data).Free`

Соотвественно присвоение `Node.Data := ^MyRecord;` в `Node.data` хранится адрес.

2. `Node.data` - только адрес памяти. Конечно, если Вы его удалите, то память выделенная под объект или запись никуда не денется.
3. Пишите отдельные процедуры построения дерева. У каждого узла есть уровень, картинка (imageindex), текст.. Все это можно сохранить в csv формате, например. А при чтении/построении в зависимости от уровня Вам надо найти узел куда добавлять. Если уровень равен текущему, то Add в тот же уровень, если больше то addchild, если меньше, то найти родителя у предыдущего с таким же уровнем и добавить.

Comment: мммм.. проблемы.  TMyNode2 = class
  public
    nom: Integer;
    comm: String;
    it: TStringList; // вот это добавил
  end; соответсвенно при создании класса - создаю, потом, перед уничтожением - пытаюсь уничтожить. правильно ли? пока даже при создании проги (код выше, т.е при присвоении item[0]) уже вылазиет access violation

Comment: Не совсем понял про присвоение. Добавлять элемент в дерево надо node := tv.items.add(... потом создать экземпляр объекта mynode2 и присвоить node.data = MyNode2; или сразу addobject -  node := tv.items.addObject(..

Comment: Items - у TTreeView такая же коллекция, как TList и TStringList. только еще есть информация об элементе дерева. И вдобавок есть конечно свойства Parent  и указатель на Child. А по сути это просто список, но многоуровневый. Просто абстрагируйтесь от визуальной реализации компонента.

Comment: С этим разобрался, спасибо. **Осталось еще тревога**: вот, если я программно создаю ноды\подноды (да, с node.data как отдельная структура). А потом программно удаляю корневую ноду у нод, имеющих подноды. Нужно ли в этом случае "пробегать" по всем поднодам и удалять эти node.data, потом сами подноды и только потом корневую? Пока корневые удаляются без вопросов, но правильно ли это? Т.е. в этом случае компилятор берет на себя ответств. по удалению всех подчиненных структур?

Comment: Node.data надо отдельно удалять думаю.Там может быть разнотипная информация абсолютно, классы, указатели на записи, что угодно. Node.data это просто ссылка на другую запись, просто адрес

Answer (score 1):

По ссылкам не ходил. Когда сам работал с TTreeView использовал справку VCL там ИМХО все описано достаточно подробно.

Вы имеете представление об ООП? Полагаю если да - многие вопросы бы исчезли. 
TTreeView точно такой же класс как и все другие. И ноды у него тоже классы. 
Вы вполне могли создать TMyNode унаследовав свойства TTreeNode или даже создать свой TTreeView с модифицированным TTreeNode который будет хранить и ссылки на записи по желанию, хотя физического смысла в этом никакого нет, если только не хочется поиграться с указателями.

А вообще чтобы лучше увидеть как устроен компонент - достаточно просто открыть его модуль. Мне думается так получится быстрее разобраться

По Вашим вопросам:
1 обьект это экземпляр класса, запись это структура данных.
2 нода только интерфейс для отображения в дереве, если хотите удалить объект необходимо освободить память им занимаемую: mynode.free или mynode.destroy нода не отвечает за обьект созданный вами (да и с чего бы ей переживать за это?)
3 вопрос видимо риторический